# How to make jQuery UI dialog not resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Does anybody know how to make the jQuery dialog non-resizable ?
At the moment, I call this:

```
var elem = $("#mydiv");
elem.dialog({
  modal: true,
  title: 'title',
  buttons: {
     Ok: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
     } // end function for Ok button
  } // end buttons
}); // end dialog
elem.dialog('open')
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use the **[resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-resizable)** option

```
 var elem = $("#mydiv");
 elem.dialog({
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    title: 'title',
    buttons: {
       Ok: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
       } //end function for Ok button
    }//end buttons
 });     // end dialog
 elem.dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 10):

Or simply:

```
$('#mydiv').dialog({resizable: false});
```